# Preserving datatype while table import using scoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, netezza

Is there any way to preserve data type while import tables from Netezza to Hive using scoop? For example Column1 with Int datatype in Netezza can be imported as Int not String. I am using

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:netezza//server/db --username --password --table table_name --hive-table table_nm
```

Using "--map-column-hive" I can manually map a column but I want to import  more than 50 tables from Netezza to Hive.I want to automate the process.

Comment: By "automating" you mean loop on the source tables to { extract the table DDL, parse the list of columns, zoom on the non-String columns, generate the list of relevant `--map-column-hive` arguments } ? You're right, that's the way I would do it. Now just do it :-)

Comment: Lolzz thanks @SamsonScharfrichter for the response..:)